# Why node server.listen do not returns to shell

Tags: node.js, process, server

Node files can describe from servers to simple scripts, even something that only prints to console:

```
//logger.js
console.log('Hello World');

// in the terminal
> node logger.js
Hello World
>
```

How `http` package (and others) do not give the command prompt back to the user; how do they keep the process alive?

```
//server
require('http').createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.end('Hello World');
}).listen(3000);

// in the terminal
> node server.js
// process stays in the foreground, no prompt back
```

Comment: From your comments on an answer, it sounds like you want to build something that behaves this way.  In general, this will happen automatically if you still have something going on (a server listening, a setTimeout waiting, etc.).  What is it that you're doing that should keep the process alive but doesn't?

Comment: @AaronDufour it's rather to understand how it works ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Node will not exit if there is a socket that is listening. So that's the TL;DR answer. (The other answers talking about the event queue are correct about that being a possible cause of programs not exiting, but that is not what is going on with `server.listen()`.)

Under the hood, `http.createServer()` is (eventually) calling [`server.listen()`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_listen_port_host_backlog_callback) Calling `server.listen()` will keep the process from exiting because `server.listen()` creates a socket. Note [from the docs for `socket.ref()`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_ref):

> Opposite of unref, calling ref on a previously unrefd socket will not let the program exit if it's the only socket left (the default behavior). If the socket is refd calling ref again will have no effect.

And [`socket.unref()`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_unref):

> Calling unref on a socket will allow the program to exit if this is the only active socket in the event system. If the socket is already unrefd calling unref again will have no effect.

If you want to go the next level in from there, I believe you would need to dive into the C or C++ the underlies Node.js/io.js.

Answer (score 5):

Node will quit when there is no event in event queue and no background task exists(which can add event to event queue) in your case, it's the later.

Comment: So what is the simplest way to act like http.createServer and keep the hand?

Comment: What do you mean keep the hand?

Comment: As in my question: let the process in foreground, no prompt back

Comment: setInterval(function() {}, 1000000) would do

Comment: Do you sincerely believe that http.createServer is coded that way?

Comment: No, you asked how to "act" like http, and keep running. For http.createServer, you can always read the code

Comment: I've asked how do http.createServer does. ps. for a majority of question in here you can always « read the code » but an explanation for someone else may be faster and simpler.